# C-API Asynchronous Batch Inference with OpenVino

Tags: openvino

I'm trying to find an example of using the C-API (not C++) asynchronous batch interface for OpenVino image inference.

I'm able to do inference on a single image at a time no problem, but its not clear to me how to expand this to batch inference with the C-API.

Does anyone have an example or reference for doing so? The OpenVino documentation is limited on this front, nor do they provide any C-based examples for doing so that I've been able to find.

EDIT: Per comment below, clarifying that the challenge is in understanding how to load up the input blobs with multiple images. The existing examples either assume the C++ interface and use vectors to move things around, or are unclear in what is idiomatic to the example (e.g. the object detection sample using the C-API)

Answer (score 0):

- You can use the following functions: *ie_infer_request_infer_async()* and *ie_infer_request_set_batch()*.
  Relevant information is available at the following link:
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/ie_c_api/group__InferRequest.html
- I suggest you refer to the following two C API based samples:

  Hello Classification C Sample
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/openvino_inference_engine_ie_bridges_c_samples_hello_classification_README.html

  Hello NV12 Input Classification C Sample
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/openvino_inference_engine_ie_bridges_c_samples_hello_nv12_input_classification_README.html
- High-level description of the process of integrating the Inference Engine into your application is available at the following page:
  https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html

Comment: Hello! Appreciate the prompt response. The challenge I'm having is in packing the input blobs with multiple images using the C approach. Other examples provided either use a single image, or do so using vectored approaches or have what may be idiomatic methods, e.g. object detection.